# Identical Tables - Unknown Column in Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I have two identical tables (apart from the name) and when trying to run the below, I get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'pages_jj.pageid' in 'where clause'`

```
SELECT pages.pageid,pages.maintext FROM databasename.pages 
WHERE pages.pageid=pages_jj.pageid LIMIT 50000;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the pages_jj table to the FROM clause, like:

```
SELECT pages.pageid,pages.maintext FROM databasename.pages, databasename.pages_jj 
WHERE pages.pageid=pages_jj.pageid LIMIT 50000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the two tables in your FROM clause, otherwise it will not know what pages_jj is.

```
SELECT pages.pageid,pages.maintext FROM databasename.pages, databasename.pages_jj
WHERE pages.pageid=pages_jj.pageid LIMIT 50000;
```

But be warned that this will return a cross product of the two tables. If **pageid** values are unique in table **pages_jj** , then no problem. However, if **pages_jj** can contain multiple lines with the same **pageid**, then lines from **pages** will be selected as many times as there are lines with the same **pagesid** in **pages_jj**... which may or may not be what you are expecting.

To get only one occurrence per matching line in **pages**, use the following:

```
SELECT pages.pageid, pages.maintext FROM databasename.pages
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT pageid FROM databasename.pages_jj WHERE pages.pageid=pages_jj.pageid) LIMIT 50000;
```